# Identify the performance bottleneck that is causing slowdowns when making numerous read and write system calls

Tags: c, performance, process, system-calls

I've developed an application that frequently utilizes pread and pwrite for reading and writing to a network devices. The operation typically takes around 7 minutes to complete.

However, when I execute two separate instances of this application concurrently but to two different devices, the completion time extends to 15 minutes. I'm seeking to understand the underlying mechanism behind pread64 and pwrite64 and identify the potential bottleneck.

It's important to note that these two processes are not accessing the same device, and there are no shared resources between them.

I'm using Linux.

Comment: It looks like only one instance of pread is executed at particular moment. You need to see the implementation

Comment: *there are no shared resources between them*  "**a** hardware device" is certainly a shared resource.

Comment: @AndrewHenle not the same device, two different devices

Comment: @0___________ is multi processes or multi threaded could solve this issue?

Comment: Please amend your question to say which OS you are using. What are the two devices? How are they connected?